# Should I use StringBuilder to concatenate two large strings?

Tags: c#, string

I have a composite with a method that calls methods on member objects.  Each method spits out a string HTML form.  The form strings can get quite large.  I know I'll always be dealing with only 2 member objects here.  Is it fine performance-wise to simply concatenate each return value or should I be using StringBuilder here?

```
    public override string RenderForm()
    {
        return _form1.RenderForm() + _form2.RenderForm();
    }
```

Comment: This strikes me as a stack overflow question

Comment: @Winston: agreed, migrating it now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In situations where you are just putting two strings together, then the string + operator (or equivalently string.Concat(string,string)) is just fine, regardless of how long the string are.

If this is part of a large tree structure with many pieces being assembled in other objects (which is what the question seems to imply), then a better approach may be to pass a StringBuilder instance to each component.

```
public override void RenderForm(StringBuilder result)
{
    _form1.RenderForm(result);
    _form2.RenderForm(result);
}

....

public override void RenderForm(StringBuilder result)
{
    result.Append("<span class='FormName'>");
    result.Append(_formName);
    result.Append("</span>");        
}
```

This would require modifying all of the components in the heirarchy, but it will likely improve memory allocation.

Comment: Yads answer and yours are both perfectly fine, but yours is more in line with composites which is what I'm dealing with.  In this case there's not a complex enough tree to warrant passing a StringBuilder around - but if there were I'd take your advice and overload RenderForm().

Answer (score 1):

You can use `string.Concat(_form1.RenderForm(), _form2.RenderForm())`

Although it is my understanding the C# compiler will convert your code into the string.Concat call anyway.

This [page](http://www.dotnetperls.com/string-concat) has a good performance analysis of the different methods.

Comment: A solid answer.  Concat would be useful in another sense if I had overridden ToString() on the two member types to render the form strings because Concat calls ToString() on each item.  In fact using ToString on members would be a better pattern if an HTML form was the **only** way to represent the members as strings. 

[MSDN Concat(obj, obj)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kbseaaft.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

This is probably not anymore efficient but it wasn't mentioned.

You could also use String.Format()

```
public override string RenderForm()
{
    return String.Format("{0}{1}", _form1.RenderForm(), _form2.RenderForm());
}
```